# Want to get maximal value, but query doesn't work

Tags: yii2

I try to program a query in Yii2, which shows me the highest value of the database. Unfortunately, I get error message:
"Call to a member function all() on string"
How to patch this problem?

```html
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use app\models\Country;

class CountryController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {


 $query = Country::find();        

 $countries = $query->select('population')->max('population')
   ->all();
   
        return $this->render('index', [
            'countries' => $countries,

        ]);
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
$query = Country::find();        

 $countries = $query->select('population')->max('population');
```

Also you can use

```
$query = Country::find();        
    $countries=$query->select('max(population) as `population`')->one();
```

It will help you :)

You have put **as** 'population' or other field name in table to assign value in second query.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code example, you are calling `all()` on the result of `max()`, which according to the error message is returning a string.

`max()` is returning the maximum value, so you probably just need to drop `... ->all()`.

Try this:

```
$countries = $query->select('population')->max('population');
```